# Difference between with-local-vars and with-bindings in Clojure

Tags: clojure, dynamic-binding

The documentation for Clojure [`with-local-vars`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-local-vars) and [`with-bindings`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-bindings) doesn't suffice for me to distinguish the two. Any hints?

Comment: I don't think 'dynamic-binding' is used correctly for your question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

New `var`s are temporarily created by `with-local-vars`. Existing `var`s are temporarily rebound by `with-bindings`. In both cases the bindings are thread-local.

Note that `with-bindings` is, as far as I can tell, primarily useful as a helper to pass bindings from another context by using a map returned by `get-thread-bindings`. The similar function `binding` would be more typical when not importing bindings.

Illustrative examples:

```
(binding [*out* (new java.io.StringWriter)] 
  (print "world!") (str "hello, " *out*))
;=> "hello, world!"

(with-local-vars [*out* (new java.io.StringWriter)] 
  (print "world!") (str "hello," *out*))
;=> world!"hello,#<Var: --unnamed-->"

(with-local-vars [foo (new java.io.StringWriter)] 
  (.write @foo "world") (str "hello, " @foo))
;=> "hello, world"

(binding [foo (new java.io.StringWriter)] 
  (.write @foo "world") (str "hello, " @foo))
;=> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: 
;     Unable to resolve var: foo in this context...
```

Answer (score 2):

(with-bindings) expects the keys of the bindings ***map to be Vars, not symbols***.  It pushes the given map of var/values onto the stack of thread local bindings and take care to
remove it after the given function returned. It is a low level function.

(with-local-vars) allows you to code in imperative style (mutating state).