# binding vs with-bindings in clojure

Tags: clojure

There are two macros `binding` and `with-bindings` to redefine dynamic vars. However both seem to have the utility, what is the difference between them ?

```
;; binding
(def :^dynamic a 10)
(binding [a 20] a) ;; => 20
a ;; => 10

;; with-bindings
(with-bindings {#'a 20}
  a) ;; => 20
a ;; => 10
```

both of them are changing the per thread dynamic scope, and resetting it to the root binding after the lexical scope is over.

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495325/2229272) to a different questions offers a theory "_... `with-bindings` is, as far as I can tell, primarily useful as a helper to pass bindings from another context by using a map returned by get-thread-bindings. The similar function `binding` would be more typical when not importing bindings._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying implementation of both is pretty much identical:

- push thread bindings (using the bindings supplied)
- try the body
- finally pop thread bindings

`binding` was added in Clojure 1.0 and `with-bindings` in 1.1. I don't see the latter used in any code tho', just the former.